# php.ini: not loading intended file

Tags: php

I made some changes to separate out the production and development environments, so that each one has it's own php.ini file.  However, the production one still loads the development one.  If I take the development one out, then no file is loaded As per phpinfo() states:

```
Loaded Configuration File   (none)
```

Even if I undo all my changes, so the original php.ini in /etc should be loaded, still no file is loaded, which is even more frustrating.

I've checked apache and local logs, nothing unusual turns up.

Upon every change, I have run:

```
service httpd restart
```

in my vhosts.conf, I have lines such as the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.example.com
    ServerAlias dev.example.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/dev.example.com/
    ...
    PHPINIDir /srv/www/dev.example.com/etc
    ...
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName stage.example.com
    ServerAlias stage.example.com
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/stage.example.com/
    ...
    PHPINIDir /srv/www/stage.example.com/etc
    ...
```

In php.ini, all that is different:

```
display_errors = Off
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

PHP 5.3.3 on CentOS

How can I figure this out, so that the proper file is being loaded for each environment?

Comment: Check here for where a congifuration file might be located, resp. where PHP looks for it (and how to tell it where to look): http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php

Comment: @CBroe: Thanks for the link, but I have been already familiar with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the `PHPINIDir` directive and your Apache works, that means that you are running PHP as Apache module. There's only one global instance of the PHP interpreter thus there can only be one php.ini.

You need to either run PHP as FastCGI or [provide settings in a different file](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.php).

Comment: OK.  That makes sense.  So, is there any way to have each virtual host use a separate php.ini file?  I looked through the linked page, didn't see anything obvious.

Comment: No, is isn't possible, that's what I tried to explain. If you don't want your settings in the document root, you'll have to use Apache files and the `php_value` and `php_flag` directives.

Comment: Thanks! Will look into the php_value directive.